# Inserting input field value to database and displaying result on same page

Tags: php, sql, insert

I am starting to learn the basics of SQL and PHP codes.

I am trying to create a simple newsletter subscription page. this would require the user to enter their email and submit. That will then get added to my database.

Now, this works well when the HTML and PHP code are separate and the submission occurs but redirects to the PHP page with the echo.

I want to get the message on the same page and I tried merging the PHP code in the page as below

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password"); 
mysql_select_db("db name"); 
$user = $_POST['email']; 
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename(columname)VALUES('$email')"; 
echo "inserted";
} 
?>

<html> 
<form method="POST" action="" > 
<label>Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" /> <br>
</form>   
</html>
```

Hoever with this code it just doesnt do anything.

What have am I doing wrong here? Appreciate your expert advice.

Comment: If this was actually executing the query it would be vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in the code, you can fix them by doing the following:

1. Save the file as a php file first. For example name it "email.php".
2. Make the form action="email.php"
3. Don't write two complete separate codes in the same file, one for php file and the other for html file like you did. You can include the html code inside the php code using heredoc syntax which allows you to include a long html code like the following:

   ```
   echo<<<_HTMLCODE
   <form method="POST" action="" > 
   <label>Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text"/>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" /> <br>
   </form> 
   _HTMLCODE;
   ```
4. In the query syntax, add $user instead $email because the variable $user contains the value submitted by the form.
5. Add a code to excute the inserted query. for example:
   mysql_query($query);

So your final code will be like this:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password"); 
    mysql_select_db("db name"); 
    $user = $_POST['email']; 
    $query = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('$user')";
    mysql_query($query); 
    echo "inserted";
}

echo<<<_HTMLCODE
<form method="POST" action="email.php" > 
<label>Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" /> <br>
</form> 
_HTMLCODE;

?>
```

I have tried the code above after I added the data of my database on the localhost and after I created a table for the emails and it worked. Here is the edited code with my database access info and the table name in my code editor:

[image: image1]

When i opened the table emails in my database, I found the email that I had submitted using the form (your modified code):

[image: image2]

(advice: use mysqli instead of mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Please use prepare statements to prevent Sql Injections.

Here is sample code try this.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "usbw", "test");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL:' . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $email = filter_input(FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, $_POST['email']); 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO table (email) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  if ($result) {
    $msg = 'Succesfully added';
  } else {
    $msg = 'OOPS Error Occured';
  }
} 
?>

 <html> 
   <form method="POST" action="" > 
     <label>Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text"/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" /> <br>
   </form>   
 </html>
```